# How to solve mismatch between http and https client when performing docker pull

Tags: docker

I have the following docker on my mac:

```
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
```

When I attempt to run

```
docker pull wurstmeister/kafka
```

I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

I was able to do docker pull just before the recent docker update.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you .

Mac Users: Update the docker preferences using the (docker) icon in top bar

Preferences -> Daemon -> Insecure Registry [Click (+) sign] -> add :port

hit "Apply & Restart" button at bottom

and if you are trying the same on windows

and  you get this error you need to create a file here:

"C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json"

and do add:

{ "insecure-registries":["wurstmeister/kafka"] }

Then restart docker using PowerShell commands: